# Send-Via-Bluetooth custom action on pcmanfm-qt

Tags: bluetooth, filemanager, lxqt

I'm trying to make custom action on pcmanfm-qt to send files/folders using blueman.

The problem is the custom action keep appearing every time i use right click button even when not selecting any file or folder even on desktop context menu on lxqt .

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Action
Name[en]=Send-via-Blueman
Icon=bluetooth
Profiles=profile-zero;

[X-Action-Profile profile-zero]
Exec=blueman-sendto %F
Name[en]=Default profile
MimeTypes=all/all;
SelectionCount==1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the MimeType line into `MimeTypes=*;!inode/directory;`. Which allows any MimeType except the one of folders.

The file then should look like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Action
Name[en]=Send-via-Blueman
Icon=bluetooth
Profiles=profile-zero;

[X-Action-Profile profile-zero]
Exec=blueman-sendto %F
Name[en]=Default profile
MimeTypes=*;!inode/directory;
SelectionCount==1
```